# Why no segmentation fault when strcpy() causes an buffer overflow?

Tags: c, overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char *a = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    char b[1];
    strcpy(b, a);
    printf("%s\n", b);
}
```

When running, it prints:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

If I make *a super long, for example, *a="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", then it will cause a segfault.

Why there is no overflow in the first case?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. It's perfectly valid for the program to spawn an elephant in your bathroom.

Comment: There is no such thing as "segmentation fault" in the C language.  You are allowed to do anything, including stepping all over other memory.  What happens when you do these things, that's what we don't know -- maybe the program will crash, maybe it will "work", maybe it works on one machine and crashes on another, etc.  That's what is called `undefined behavior`.

Comment: This HAS to be a multi-dup, but cannot find one off-hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No segmentation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562017/no-segmentation-fault)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A segmentation fault happens when your program tries to access memory that doesn't belong to your program's virtual address space; this will not happen if you just overwrite a bit of stuff right after your original copy destination.

Answer (score 0):

There is buffer overflow, it doesn't mean it will always couse segmentation fault. It is undefined behaviour - there MAY be segfault. It depends on what is "placed" right after your variable in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Appearing to work, or, for that matter, not crashing, is a valid form of undefined behavior. *Anything* can happen when your program has UB. That's why it's highly undesirable.